# Problem with Firestore Snapshot Listener in Android Compose and Callback Lambda

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

In my Compose Project I wanted to implement a Snapshot Listener that updates the LiveData of my ViewModel. To keep the code related to firestore apart from logic in the viewModel I added a Repository with the following funtion:

```
override fun getInvitations(onDataUpdate: (List<Session>) -> Unit) {
        val invitationsQuery = db.collection("invitations").whereEqualTo("player_id", auth.currentUser?.uid)
        val listener = invitationsQuery.addSnapshotListener{ querySnapshot, exception ->
            if (exception != null){
                Log.w("ONLINE", "Error handling Snapshot",exception)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            val sessions = mutableListOf<Session>()
            querySnapshot?.documents?.forEach{
                sessions.add(it.toSession())
            }
            onDataUpdate(sessions)
        }
        listeners.add(listener)
    }
```

The idea was then to only call this function once in the viewModel and give it a Lambda that updates the LiveData like this:

```
multiplayerRepository.getInvitations {
            invitations.value = it
        }
```

The problem is that there is no Recomposition caused although the LiveData gets updated. Multiple Logs gave me that.

I already tried using `postValue()` instead of `invitations.value = ...`with no other effect.

I really want to keep the LiveData away from the Repository, but am aware it will be an alternative to get the LiveData from the Listener.

Anything appreciated.

Comment: Where are you logging to confirm the live data changes? The only place it could make sense to log it would be inside an observer. And can you show your code where you observe the live data as state?

Comment: I just call observeAsState() on the LiveData inside my Composable. I now also added a Text and put livedata.value inside. The Text shows me the right LiveData. Seems like the Logic is not the Problem after all. But still my other UI-Elements are not updated. Which is sort of interesting

Comment: Did you remember to wrap your `observeAsState` call with `remember { }`? If you only describe what you did without showing the actual code, we can only take wild guesses at what the bugs are, unless your fundamental understanding is completely wrong, which I don’t see here.

Comment: I thought it would be unnecessary to wrap the observeAsState in a remember. It worked before without. Also to mention it: I get an Error when I write `remember{ viewModel.liveData.observeAsState() }`  saying `Composable calls are not allowed inside the calculation parameter of inline fun <T> remember(crossinline calculation: () -> TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T` 
Also the description of observeAsState says: `causing recomposition of every State.value usage` 

Gonna do another question later today, the point of the conversation is not the one of the question anymore.

Comment: I’m sorry, you’re right. You don’t need `remember` for observing, only for when you directly create your own MutableState in a composition. Can you show how you get your view mode reference in the activity/fragment/composition?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75237549/livedata-update-does-not-cause-recompostion-of-my-composables) :)

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-multiple-firebase-products-in-kotlin-16aade81ffec) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was rather simple.

This  was not a problem of Compose nor was Firebase doing weird stuff. It was the Code I wrote.

It turned out that I overlooked that I deleted a function that queries Userdata when I deleted another old function. Without it my UI cannot update due to a empty list.

I went through my commits multiple times and missed it multiple times. But the moment I saw that was a great relief.

Still thanks to all your help.