# LiveData update does not cause Recompostion of my Composables

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

In my ViewModel I have a few LiveData objects like this one:

```
val invitations = MutableLiveData(listOf<Session>())
```

I have set up multiple Firestore Snapshot Listeners that should update my LiveData. Therefore I give the function that instantiates the listener a lambda like this:

```
repository.getInvitations {
   invitations.value = it
   Log.d("ONLINE", "Receiving Invitations.")
}
```

Here is the repository function:

```
override fun getInvitations(onDataUpdate: (List<Session>) -> Unit) {
        val invitationsQuery = db.collection("invitations").whereEqualTo("player_id", auth.currentUser?.uid)
        val listener = invitationsQuery.addSnapshotListener{ querySnapshot, exception ->
            if (exception != null){
                Log.w("ONLINE", "Error handling Snapshot",exception)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            val sessions = mutableListOf<Session>()
            querySnapshot?.documents?.forEach{
                sessions.add(it.toSession())
            }
            onDataUpdate(sessions)
        }
        listeners.add(listener)
    }
```

In my Composable I observe the LiveData with `observeAsState()` from the viewModel

```
val invitations = viewModel.invitations.observeAsState()
```

In my UI I use the received state as usual with `invitation.value`.
That worked quite fine for a while. Before I had another normal firestore query running in the init block of my viewModel that updated some other LiveData. But since I did not needed that function anymore and deleted it, my UI is not updating anymore.

My instant suggestion is that the lambda callback in the snapshot listener is not updating my liveData correctly. Which I more or less proved wrong by adding a Text element under the rest of my UI where I also use the same state. That text somehow can detect the change in the LiveData.

My other UI code is quite complex but here is quick overview:

```
@Composable
fun Screen(viewModel: MyviewModel = koinViewModel()){
   val invitations = viewModel.invitations.observeAsState()

   MyUIElement(invitations.value)

   Text("${invitations.value}")
}
```

If more of the UI code is needed I can give it.

I also tried asking ChatGPT about this. It mentioned that snapshot listeners are running in background threads and the LiveData can only detect data changes in the Main thread. But it did not seem to be helpful to just add a `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main) {}` to update it in the Main thread.

Also this cant really be the problem for my UI to not update, because my Text is showing all my changes to the firestore data if I update it in the online console.

This was bothering me for a while now. I really dont want to refactor all my Code now. A quick fix would be appreciatd. :)

Comment: Is Session a `data class`? If not, does it at least have `hashcode` and `equals` defined? And can you show what the function `repository.getInvitations` looks like at the source?

Comment: Yes it is a data class. I Also wrote an extension function for a DocumentSnapshot that I get in the Listener to cast it for me into a Session. It is just receiving the values for the specified keys.

Comment: Is it a mutable class, where you're mutating the items in the list by modifying their `var`s instead of creating new instances?

Comment: no. I always create new Instance. Even so I would update the Livedata with `liveData.value = instance` which should definitely update the LiveData

Comment: It updates the LiveData, but I'm not positive about State. If State works like StateFlow, it smartly avoids a recomposition if two "equal" objects are emitted in a row, which would break if it's comparing the same mutable object to itself. `observeAsState` wraps the LiveData in State, so it might be introducing that behavior, just like you'd get if you did `liveData.asFlow().stateIn(...)`. But anyway, you're not doing that. I'm stumped about your problem.

Comment: The thing is I am updating it with a not equal object. And the data that should be shown does not appear. Could there be some weird List behavior that I oversee again? I just realised that I almost always use the State by iterating over the List with a for loop or by calling `.isNotEmpty()` or `.isNotNull()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251396/discussion-between-berni-and-tenfour04).